# deploy to multiple OpenShift Container Registries

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have created three openshift container registries. For example I will use the below addresses:

https://openshift-registry-1.com
https://openshift-registry-2.com
 
https://openshift-registry-3.com

I am looking for a way or a tool to push the same image to all three in one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way to move images from one registry to anther is [oc image mirror](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#managing-images-mirror-registry-images)

For example, to copy an image from **Docker Hub** to the integrated registry use the following command:

`$ oc image mirror docker.io/library/busybox:latest 172.30.0.0/16/myproject/toybox:latest`

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) cli for this from inside my cicd/orchestration tool of choice (e.g. Jenkins, Ansible Tower, etc). skopeo is a command line utility that performs various operations on container images and image repositories.

Take a look at the official OpenShift blog post [Promoting container images between container registries with skopeo](https://blog.openshift.com/promoting-container-images-between-registries-with-skopeo/) for example usage.

The example they post there:

```
def namespace, appReleaseTag, webReleaseTag, prodCluster, prodProject, prodToken

pipeline {
agent {
label 'skopeo'
}
stages {
stage('Choose Release Version') {
steps {
script {
openshift.withCluster() {
// Login to the production cluster
namespace = openshift.project()
prodCluster = env.PROD_MASTER.replace("https://","insecure://")
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${namespace}-prod-credentials", usernameVariable: "PROD_USER", passwordVariable: "PROD_TOKEN")]) {
prodToken = env.PROD_TOKEN
}

// Get list of tags in the ImageStream to show the release-manager
def appTags = openshift.selector("istag").objects().collect { it.metadata.name }.findAll { it.startsWith 'app:' }.collect { it.replaceAll(/app:(.*)/, "\$1") }.sort()
timeout(5) {
def inputs = input(
ok: "Deploy",
message: "Enter release version to promote to PROD",
parameters: [
string(defaultValue: "prod", description: 'Name of the PROD project to create', name: 'PROD Project Name'),
choice(choices: appTags.join('\n'), description: '', name: 'Application Release Version'),
]
)
appReleaseTag = inputs['Application Release Version']
prodProject = inputs['PROD Project Name']
}
}
}
}
}
stage('Create PROD') {
steps {
script {
openshift.withCluster(prodCluster, prodToken) {
openshift.newProject(prodProject, "--display-name='CoolStore PROD'")
}
}
}
}
stage('Promote Images to PROD') {
steps {
script {
openshift.withCluster() {
def srcApplicationRef = openshift.selector("istag", "app:${appReleaseTag}").object().image.dockerImageReference
def destApplicationRef = "${env.PROD_REGISTRY}/${prodProject}/app:${appReleaseTag}"
def srcToken = readFile "/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
sh "skopeo copy docker://${srcApplicationRef} docker://${destApplicationRef} --src-creds openshift:${srcToken} --dest-creds openshift:${prodToken}"
}
}
}
}
stage('Deploy to PROD') {
steps {
script {
openshift.withCluster(prodCluster, prodToken) {
openshift.withProject(prodProject) {
def template = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openshift-labs/myapp/myapp-template.yaml'
openshift.apply(
openshift.process("-f", template, "-p", "APPLICATION_IMAGE_VERSION=${appReleaseTag}", "-p", "IMAGE_NAMESPACE=")
)
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
```